# Adding Vuetify via Vue CLI leads to "Module not found" error

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to install Vuetify on top of a fresh Vue project just created via Vue CLI > `vue create vuetify`. However I end up with this every time when I serve the project to the browser:

[image]

Additionally, in the terminal that launched the server, I get:

[image]

...suggesting the Vuetify plugin isn't installed, which is precisely what I thought `vue add vuetify` was supposed to do.

Here's the exact repro steps:

1. `vue create vuetify`
2. "Please pick a preset". Choice: "Default ([Vue 2] babel, eslint)"
3. (Vue CLI does its thing, creating project)
4. `cd vuetify`
5. `npm run serve`
6. (Default Vue project page shows up in browser @ localhost:8080)
7. `vue add vuetify`
8. "WARN  There are uncommitted changes in the current repository, it's recommended to commit or stash them first. Still proceed? (y/N)"
9. `y` (I have no idea what this is about)
10. "Choose a preset". Choice: "Default (recommended)"
11. (Vue CLI does its things, installing Vuetify)
12. Browser/terminal errors...

What am I doing wrong?

(Node.js version: v14.15.5; Vue CLI version: v4.5.13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the server should solve the issue: stop the app and then run `npm run serve` (if you're using `npm`).

The problem is that the app was running when executing `vue add vuetify` so it wasn't restarted automatically after installation.

Comment: Aha! Thank you; so simple a fix in the end. Do you know what step 8 is about?

Comment: Not sure, I think it's ``vue-cli`` giving you a warning when adding a plugin so you don't lose any uncommited changes. When creating a project, a ``.git`` file is created with it to keep track of the changes. Adding ``vuetify`` in this case would do changes to your files and create new ones that might affect your code, so probably this warning is for you to be aware of such consequences. I advise researching more on this if you're interested.